# How to compile classicsudoku?

Tags: compiling

I've just downloaded a game from http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicsudoku/?source=directory
I don't know how to compile it, because there is no configure file. and autogen.sh command shows "autogen.sh: command not found".

Answer (score 3):

The developer of this particular piece of software was lazy enough not to care about platforms other than Windows. It may or may not work at all.

First of all, you need to re-create the Makefiles, by running:

```
qmake -project
qmake
```

Then try running:

```
make
```

You will probably be missing a lot of libraries and header files on the first try. Go ahead and google each error you get, and hope for the best.

**EDIT**: By the way, there are a number of Sudoku games available for Ubuntu in the repositories. Look for them in the [Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center), or from the terminal:

```
apt-cache search sudoku
```

Then install by running, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install ksudoku
```

Comment: im newb in linux, so i decided to compile first program, thats why i've choosen a gui game/app (suduku) for this.

Comment: vivek@vivek-N61PB-M2S:/usr/local/src/0.9.1/sudoku$ qmake
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
vivek@vivek-N61PB-M2S:/usr/local/src/0.9.1/sudoku$ make
Makefile:66: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Comment: Try running `qmake-qt4` or `qmake-qt5`. If both fail, you might be missing `qmake` altogether, so you need to install it: `sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake`

Comment: ok qmake-qt4 worked. now i got error-
vivek@vivek-N61PB-M2S:/usr/local/src/0.9.1/sudoku$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QApplication>
                        ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: I quickly looked through the code and it's purely a QT application so should run without problems under *nix as well (and lazy enough not to provide an untested makefile? So is RMS just lazy for not providing a VS project for his code?). @user284530 You'll need to install the QT development headers.